# Pass value in-between angular JS controller and services

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I am trying to get the user query from html using `ng-click`. I want to make a https call using the value which I fetch from ng-click. I can see the data in **Alert--1** but in **Alert--2** i get `undefined`. on internet I read that passing values using **services** is the best practice.Please correct me if I am wrong.

My controller

```
mainApp.controller('searchController',function($scope,searchString){

  $scope.getQuery = function(userq)  // its ng-click="getQuery(userq)" on Search button
  {
    $scope.userq=userq;
    alert('Alert--1'+userq);  // its working fine
    searchString.setSearchString(userq);
  };
});

//====================

mainApp.controller('fetchQueryResultController',function($scope,searchString){
   var searchStr = searchString.getSearchString();
   alert('Alert--2--'+searchStr);   //   Undefined
  // Later I'll use this value to fetch data from Watson search(Django) using $https call
});
```

My service:

```
mainApp.factory('searchString', function () {
    var qVal ;

    return {
        setSearchString:function (query) {
            qVal = query;
        },
        getSearchString:function () {
            return qVal;
        }
    };
});
```

Routing:

```
.when('/search', {
     templateUrl: "../static/views/seachResult.html",
     controller: "fetchQueryResultController"
  })
```

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: please don't abandon posts to create new ones asking the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460627/pass-variable-inside-same-controller-from-ng-click-angular-js), you are getting mostly the same responses there as you were getting here.  instead, choose one question and clarify your problem if you don't find the responses helpful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a service is OK. Take a look at this, is quite clear for begginers:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

`alert('Alert--2'+searchStr);`  is showing undefined because it is being executed before `$scope.getQuery` obviously. Controller's initialization is done before `ng-init` evaluates the expression.

In your case I believe it is better to fire an event when the data is set, so the second controller gets notified. This is being done with `$on` and `$emit`.

Here is a plunker with your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/97mVwbWmoOH3F7m8wbN0?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('searchController',function($scope,searchString){

  $scope.searchText;

  $scope.getQuery = function(userq)  // its ng-click="getQuery(userq)" on Search button
  {
    $scope.userq=userq;
    alert('Alert--1'+userq);  // its working fine
    searchString.setSearchString(userq, $scope);
  };
});

//====================

app.controller('fetchQueryResultController',function($scope, $rootScope, searchString){
   var searchStr = searchString.getSearchString;

   $scope.getData = function(){
     searchStr = searchString.getSearchString();
     alert('Alert--2--'+ searchStr); 
   }

   $rootScope.$on('dataModified', function(){
     $scope.getData();
   });

});

//====================

app.factory('searchString', function ($rootScope) {
    var qVal ;

    return {
        setSearchString:function (query) {
            qVal = query;
            $rootScope.$emit('dataModified');
        },
        getSearchString:function () {
            return qVal;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I have edited the code and have now created 2 controllers. One sets the user query and the other is called when view is rendered. I want to make my code woork, so made some changes as per the video, M i missing something?

Comment: I have edited my answer for showing you a better solution, take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

this alert undefined

```
var searchStr = searchString.getSearchString();
 alert('Alert--2'+searchStr);
```

becuase `qVal` hasn't set yet

`qVal` set when `getQuery` get called but that time `alert2` already executed

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have your factory return an object and let your controllers work with a reference to the same object:

**JS:**

```
// declare the app with no dependencies
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('searchString', function() {
  var qVal;

  return {
    setSearchString: function(query) {
      qVal = query;
    },
    getSearchString: function() {
      return qVal;
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('setSearchController', function($scope, searchString) {
  $scope.setQuery = function(userq) {
    $scope.userq = userq;
    searchString.setSearchString(userq);
  };
});

myApp.controller('fetchQueryResultController', function($scope, searchString) {

  $scope.getQuery = function(user) {
    alert(searchString.getSearchString());
  };

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="setSearchController">
      <button ng-click="setQuery('Shohel')">Set</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div ng-controller="fetchQueryResultController">
      <button ng-click="getQuery()">Get</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here is similar fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27mk1n1o/)

Comment: Hi,m not able to figure out the way u want me to handle my existing routing code. I dont want to put ng-click. Its just that - why my service scope is not working outside `getQuery` ng-click function. I can use both **get** and **set**  from service inside `getQuery` but not from outside.

Comment: Please write plunker or fiddler that will help us for clear understanding