# pass variable inside same controller from ng-click angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the variable value which has been assigned inside ng-click function

```
mainApp.controller('setSearchController',function($scope) {

  $scope.getQuery = function(userq)  //ng-click function
  {
    $scope.userq=userq;
  };

  alert($scope.userq);  // showing Undefined even after the click is made
// Once clicked I want to use **userq** value to make one $https call
//  apart from services,How to use userq here outside getQuery scope
});
```

before using ng-click , its ok to get undefined value but what I am trying to do is to use the same controller for another view , which will be rendered after the ng-click happens

```
.when('/search', {
   templateUrl: "../static/views/seachResult.html",
 controller: "setSearchController"
})
```

so I want to fetch some searched data in searchResult.html view after `$https` call

Comment: as value is assigned in scope you can use it anywhere in `setSearchController` controller

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: edited my code

Comment: why is `alert` outside the function?

Comment: @charlietfl: Because I want to make an https call using that value and display the response

Comment: The alert is hit as soon as the page loads so it's undefined because nobody sets it. As soon as someone clicks the getQuery you will have it defined.

Comment: @Shashank that doesn't make any sense. Please show all relevant code and explain your problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl: Hope my question is more clear now

Comment: If you use the same controller for another view, this other view will have a new $scope instance, and a new controller instance. Controllers are not singletons like services. Each view has its own instance. If you need to share data between controllers, then use a service.

Comment: @JBNizet: If u add `$scope.var="someVal"` outside getQuery function inside the same controller. You can see it as `{{ var }}` on **seachResult.html** .

Comment: @JBNizet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459234/pass-value-in-between-angular-js-controller-and-services

Comment: I don't see a function that an `ng-click` could call here, and I don't see the HTML showing any `ng-click` or what it *might be trying* to call.

Comment: also, your response to @charlietfl doesn't really make any sense,  using a variable in an https call has nothing to do with the fact that one of your code statements isn't in the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answer here:
 [Pass value in-between angular JS controller and services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459234/pass-value-in-between-angular-js-controller-and-services)

It is the same question, I have solved your problem with event listeners using $on and $emit

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="getQuery('myVal')">Test</button>
  <button ng-click="consoleIt(myVal)">Console</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.getQuery = function(a){
        $scope[a] = a;
    }
    $scope.consoleIt = function(a){
        console.log(a);
    }
  }]);
```

The `getQuery` function creates a new property on your scope. The property's name is equal to what is passed (string) as agrument to the function. `consoleIt` simply console logs its agrument. `myVal` is undefined until you click the `test` button. You can also pass a variable (instead of string) to `getQuery`, in this case just remove the quotes from inside of parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

Move alert inside statement function getQuery.

```
mainApp.controller('setSearchController', function($scope) {
      $scope.userq = null; 
      $scope.getQuery = function(userq)  //ng-click function
      {
          $scope.userq=userq;
          alert($scope.userq);
      };
    });
```

or this solution

```
mainApp.controller('setSearchController', ['$scope', '$window', setSearchController]);

    function setSearchController ($scope, $window) {
          $scope.userq = null; 
          $scope.getQuery = function(userq)  //ng-click function
          {
              $scope.userq=userq;
              $window.alert($scope.userq);
          };
        }
```